# How to avoid Dispatcher Unhandled Exceptions bubbling up to wrapper?

Tags: dispatcher, unhandled-exception

I have a WPF application...and I have a WPF parent application (which is third party)...

and this third party app uses my app's DLLS to load my app as one of it child.

My app has following code to handle unhanlded exceptions.

```
 Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledException += new DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(App_Dispatcher_UnhandledException);
```

But the third party parent app also have the same code...and when ever an eception occurs...parent app's function get called first.

Is there anyway to restrict the exception to bubble upto parent app level?